# How am I notified that the peer review of my edit has been done?

Tags: support, answers, notifications, review, edits

I edited an answerer's answer, and it went to peer review.  I can see my edit, of course, but how do I know whether or not it has been approved?  I will accept the answer once I know that my edit has been approved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your overall track record on edits (and a summary of accept/reject for your latest ones)

- go to any successful suggested edit, and click on `Edited x minutes ago`

[image]

- Find your edit summary, and click on `Suggested`, and scroll to the bottom of the screen to get the newest info.

[image]

Comment: Oh- _there_!  Yes, it actually says it: **Approved 8 hours ago by Ian Ringrose, Jeff Atwood**.  A bit circuitous, but certainly unambiguous.

Comment: @Chap Yes, I don't think there is any other way to find out (aside from indirectly when earning the +2 as Siva has pointed out).  If the "thanks for your edit" banner disappears when you view the question or answer again, then you know something has happened.

Comment: Isn't edit approval the *only* thing that can give you +2 rep? If so, then it should be simple to make the connection.

Comment: @Cody (Except for selecting an answer, which isn't germane) Yes, if you edit is accepted, sure, but telling the difference between an edit that's been rejected or one still pending isn't possible, unless you view the original post to see if the banner is gone.  To check your "track record", there is no other way, as this information is not maintained in the activity section.

Comment: If it were thought important by the SE developers to communicate this particular bit of information, I'm sure they could come up with an ingeniously simple way of doing it.  Like a "your edit was approved" banner!  :-D  ... 'nuff said.

Comment: @Chap: I wouldn't call a banner "ingenious". That seems like more noise than *most* people would want. They're trying to actively reduce the number of obnoxious banners that you get, not increase them.

Comment: @Cody: my point is that I would like to have received _specific_ notification of the outcome of a pending event.  It certainly doesn't have to be a banner.  But simply noticing one's rep change is too subtle for me.  Just MHO.

Answer (score 8):

Since you have less than 2000 points on SO, I believe you will get +2 points for your edit, if approved. See this FAQ section, https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation. It describes about the +2 credit.

[image: See, I told ya]

On your profile, click `Reputation` tab and select `by post` option, you should see +2 reputation points with `edit` against the post that you edited. Click on the link and you will be taken directly to the post that you edited.

[image: Profile reputations]

Comment: That would explain the mysterious two extra pts. this morning ;-)  Something less ambiguous would be nice, but that will do.

Comment: What I mean is, couldn't I have been awarded those points for any of a number of reasons?  Or is there a way to find out specifically what each reputation award was for?  If not, I'd call it ambiguous.

Comment: Great illustrations!  Had to give the checkmark to @jonsca, as it most clearly indicates the exact status of the specific edit.  (I have so few Reputation points that I still notice individual increments such as this morning - in general, however, I wouldn't consider it to be the sort of "notification" I was originally looking for.)

Comment: @Chap: Sure, you got to mark the post that answered your question. Not the one that looks pretty. :-)